# Add users to a certain AD group depending on their City

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Fairly new to all of this but what I am trying add users to a certain AD group who meet the following criteria

1. They are not disabled in AD.
2. In a specific office/city (we set this within AD, AD > users account> address > 'City' field).

I've got to below, issue is that we have 5 offices and I am struggling to get the correct variables. So if a user is in the London (according to City filed in AD) they are added to a AD group called 'London-office'. If they are not based in London it then loops through to the next office and so on.

```
Get-ADuser -SearchBase 'DC=XXX' -filter * |
    Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, City, Enabled |
    Where {$_.enabled.tostring() -eq -and $_.City -eq 'London'}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the command above?

Comment: It's generally considered good practice in PowerShell to filter your results as far to the left as you can. In this case, you should be able to filter right on the `Get-ADUser`: `Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'DC=XXX' -Filter "City -eq 'London'"`

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I think the issue here is he is looking at all cities and doing a specific action for each one. There are multiple ways of addressing this.

Comment: Hi Jeff, When i run the above command it gives me the user names of all enabled account that have 'London' added to the city field in AD (which is what i am after. I am struggling with getting the correct syntax for it to loop though with different offices. I.e if the user is not in the London office it then checks the Frankfurt office etc

Comment: All the groups have all the cities in the name or is there another mapping method? City=London => Group=London Office. Is that always the case? This would be the difference from "automatic" group membership and using a switch statement for manual assignment.

Comment: @Matt All the groups have all the cities in. So if a users has City=London, they need to be added to a group called "London Office". 

Ideally the script needs to going through our AD users, check the 'City' field and if it is London it matches and adds to AD group 'London Office' If not it checks the next office, such as Frankfurt, then New York etc

Comment: `foreach ($user in (Get-ADUser)) { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "$($user.city) Office" -Member $user }` looks like it should work, assuming that the groups are all named "London Office", "Paris Office", "Frankfurt Office", "New York Office", et multae ceterae ad nauseum.

Comment: @Matt - Good catch; fixed in the comment. I'm not exactly in a position to test, and it's not something I often have to do...

Comment: Actually, it might be better to loop on the cities: `ForEach ($city in @("New York", "Frankfurt", "Paris", "London", "Tokyo")) { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "$($city) Office" -Member (Get-ADUser -Filter "City -eq '$($city)'") }`

Comment: The reason for looping on the cities is that `Add-ADGroupMember` can take multiple member names. See [the `Add-ADGroupMember` TechNet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To cut down on repetition you need to look at this one of two different ways. If your groups and cities all follow the same naming patterns...

```
+----------+----------------+
|   City   |     Group      |
+----------+----------------+
| London   | London Group   |
| New York | New York Group |
+----------+----------------+
```

Then you can apply users to groups directly with a minimal amount of code. If there are discrepancies among the groups.

```
+----------+--------------+
|   City   |    Group     |
+----------+--------------+
| London   | Ldn Group    |
| New York | NYCity Group |
+----------+--------------+
```

Then you might need to build a switch statement to manually assign cities members to groups.

Note that City is not returned by default so you need to add it. Also it is preferred that you use `-Filter` to reduce your selection set and this also improves performance.

```
Get-ADuser -SearchBase 'DC=XXX' -filter {Enabled -eq $True} -Properties City | ForEach-Object{
    $_ | Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "$($_.City) Group"
}
```

If the groups are not that easy to map over then something like this would also work.

```
$users = Get-ADuser -SearchBase 'DC=XXX' -filter {Enabled -eq $True} -Properties City 
foreach($user in $users){
    $addToGroup = switch($user.City){
        "London"{"London Group";Break}
        "New York"{"NYCity Collective";Break}
        Default{""}
    }

    # Check to be sure a match was made. 
    if($addToGroup){
        $user | Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $addToGroup
    }
}
```

**Note:** Switch clause will all be evaluated. So even if "London" is a match it will still try to match "New York". While there is not likely going to be overlap `break` will ensure there isn't. Also, none of the above accounts for groups that might not exist or if the users are already in the groups. `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and `-WhatIf` might be useful for testing and even production use.

There are multiple other perfectly valid approaches to this as well. The core concept will still be the same in either case.

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down, much more manageable for my eyes! I will give this ago tomorrow and let you know!